# Library required when moving to another pc

Tags: c, linux, curl

I have done a simple `C` program that copies files from `ftp` using `curl` library.

I have done it on `Ubuntu` linux machine and now I would like to distribute it to `Debian` and `Ubuntu` PC's. I'm planning to copy output file to these machines. What other files need to be coppied to these PC'? Do I need to install curl using command `apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are distributing your software as binary files, you do NOT need to require the `-dev` packages. Only the libraries in binary form are needed.

What does contain a `-dev` package are header files needed by the compiler to build the object files and no more. Once you have a binary form for your executable, only the binary library is needed.

Comment: Is it good just copy binary lib from my computer to another pc with different distribution? Where are placed curl binary libs, I just see headers? Where I need to place binary to another computer - just in the same location like executable?

Comment: Usually, the localization of the libraries is performed through ldconfig. You do not have to care about it. If the binary of libcurl is installed, then your program will find it.